# How do I decompress a $_POST array?

Tags: php, arrays, post, gzip, httpservice

I have a $_POST that is in array format, and when the $_POST is over 256B, because what sends it has limitations, it's automatically compressed using gzip. I can't prevent that, but what I can do is decompress it (using PHP) and still have it as an array. I think. gzuncompress is only for strings.
I can use this: (to turn it into a string that's decompresssed)

```
$post_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$post_body = (ord(substr($post_body,0,1)) == 31 ? gzinflate(substr($post_body,10,-8)) : $post_body);
```

But that is a string, and I can't write PHP for the life of me, I had help writing what I currently got but the helper is stumped here.

Assuming the $post_body is:

```
userid=&name=&level=&exp=&key1=&key2=&key3=&key4=&key5=&key6=&key7=&key8=&key9=&key10=&key11=&key12=
```

How would I turn that back into an array? Like, how I could previously do:

```
$userid = $_POST["userid"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
```

and so on. I sort of don't know how to see the $_POST as an array though. The method automatically converts it from the string to the array. But then I need to handle it in PHP as an array. I don't see the array though. I can echo it, but it shows up as

```
Array
```

Thats all.

Help is very much appreciated, I'm storing data with this, and I had to take down a 'game' of mine to deal with this problem. Up until now $_POST was under 256B, so I didn't have the problem. :/

Edit: thanks @Marcin Orlowski for telling me b = bit and B = bytes

Comment: So you have 2 questions?  1. how to convert a query string into an array? 2. how to access the array?

Comment: BTW: `it's over 256b` -> `b` stands for `bits`, while `B` stands for `bytes`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte

Comment: add a `header("accept: gzip/deflate")` but i feel like the server should automatically do that for you..

Comment: @AbraCadaver Both i guess, yes. I don't HAVE to be able to access the array, but it'd be nice to know how my program sends the $_POST

Comment: Also, what's special about 256B?  Check http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

Comment: @AbraCadaver I'm not entirely sure. It just mentions it on their wiki, and I've tested to make sure it actually does compress at that size (257 characters and higher) http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/HttpService

Comment: @AbraCadaver Nothing, the system sending the data to PHP has limitations.

Comment: @PootieTang Would I just put that after the `<?php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) like this:

```
$post_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$post_body = (ord(substr($post_body,0,1)) == 31 ? gzinflate(substr($post_body,10,-8)) : $post_body);

parse_str($post_body);

// Now just call $userid or $name, etc...
```

Answer (score -3):

You simply call the array and the desired index:

```
echo yourArray['yourIndex'];
```